# Enum and IEnumerable in C#

Tags: c#, enums

my TIME Enum contains Annual, Monthly, weekly, daily and Hourly.

Here I want to decide which is the minimum and want to return that.

How can I do this ? Here is the code I tried.

```
private Time DecideMinTime(IEnumerable<Time> g)
{
    var minTime = Time.Hourly;
    foreach (var element in g)
    {
        minTime = element;
    }
    return minTime;
}
```

Comment: What defines "minimum?"

Comment: If you're doing the loop, you need to initialize minTime to the first value in the sequence, and then check in your loop `if (element < minTime) minTime = element`, assuming like cdhowie suggests, that your enums are ordered correctly (lower int values for hourly than for annual, for example)

Comment: Define your enum in the order smallest to largest and then cast to int - (int)Time

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that the numeric value of the enum elements decides what the minimum is:

```
private Time DecideMinTime(IEnumerable<Time> g)
{
    if (g == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("g"); }

    return (Time)g.Cast<int>().Min();
}
```

If the numeric values indicate the opposite order then you would use `.Max()` instead of `.Min()`.

---

As indicated, the numeric order is not consistent.  This can be worked around simply by using a mapping indicating the correct order:

```
static class TimeOrdering
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Time, int> timeOrderingMap;

    static TimeOrdering()
    {
        timeOrderingMap = new Dictionary<Time, int>();

        timeOrderingMap[Time.Hourly] = 1;
        timeOrderingMap[Time.Daily] = 2;
        timeOrderingMap[Time.Weekly] = 3;
        timeOrderingMap[Time.Monthly] = 4;
        timeOrderingMap[Time.Annual] = 5;
    }

    public Time DecideMinTime(IEnumerable<Time> g)
    {
        if (g == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("g"); }

        return g.MinBy(i => timeOrderingMap[i]);
    }

    public TSource MinBy<TSource, int>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> self,
        Func<TSource, int> ordering)
    {
        if (self == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("self"); }
        if (ordering == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("ordering"); }

        using (var e = self.GetEnumerator()) {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) {
                throw new ArgumentException("Sequence is empty.", "self");
            }

            var minElement = e.Current;
            var minOrder = ordering(minElement);

            while (e.MoveNext()) {
                var curOrder = ordering(e.Current);

                if (curOrder < minOrder) {
                    minOrder = curOrder;
                    minElement = e.Current;
                }
            }

            return minElement;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Numeric value is not the one that is deciding the minimum. In my enum, Monthy=1, Annual = 2, Hourly = 3, Weekly = 4, Daily = 5. I know its not good declaration but we started the application long back with Monthly and Annually and recently added Hourly, weekly and daily.

Comment: @user3757426 Which is the "minimum?"  Annual or hourly?

Comment: Hourly is the minimum.

Comment: @cdhowie g.Min would return the mapped `int`. you need to add another lookup.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez That always catches me off-guard.  One moment.

Comment: @cdhowie me too, we definitely need a MinBy method.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez And I abstracted the MinBy logic out into its own extension method for reusability.

Comment: @cdhowie Unable to create MinBy method. TSource is throwing error. In my code, System.Linq unable to generate TSource

Comment: @cdhowie I should've mentioned -- Jon Skeet's [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) library also contains a `MinBy()`, which is almost exactly the same as yours, except he also abstracts out the order value type (which is hardcoded as `int` in your example).

Comment: @ErenErsönmez How to implement MinBy in my Code ? It is showing C#: Unknown menthod MinBy of 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumberable<Core.Models.Time>

Comment: @user3757426 just copy the class above in your code somewhere, except probably make the `MinBy` method public. It was probably left as `private` by mistake.

Comment: @cdhowie This hasn't fix my issue. infact I got confused how this TSource and MinBy will work. I never heard of these before. Is it new in 4.5 ?

Comment: @user3757426 It is just a generic extension method, which would be supported in 3.5.  It must be defined in a static class.  You can also make it private and call it as `MinBy(g, i => ...)`.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez I thought about writing a more generic version that accepted a `TOrdering ... where TOrdering : IComparable<TOrdering>`, but then we have to deal with null checks, etc.  In other words I could have done it, but it would have been overkill here.

Comment: @JustinMorgan Which null checks?

Comment: Never mind, those are on the IEnumerables and the Func. Not sure what I was thinking.

Answer (score 3):

To make it easier you can assign int values to your enum:

```
enum Time : byte {Hourly=1, Daily=2, Weekly=3, Monthly=4, Annual=5};
```

and then

```
private static Time DecideMinTime(IEnumerable<Time> g)
{            
   return g.Min();                        
}
```

That way you avoid casting back and forth.